# How can I return a return a URL from the chrome.history.search?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I have the following block of code

```
function findLastEpisodeLink_helper(title) {

  var url;

  chrome.history.search(
   {
    'text': title,
    'maxResults': 1,
    'startTime': 0
   },

  function(historyItems) {

    url = historyItems[0]["url"];
    // console.log(url);
  }

  );
  // console.log(url);
  return url;
}
```

Whenever i use this function it returns undefined, I found that its because this is a asyncronous call.

Can someone help me fix this code similar solution dont seems to work.

Comment: if you are sure it is an async call add `await` keyword before `chrome.history.search(`

Comment: It's not async. It uses an asynchronous callback. See the linked topic for examples of using asynchronous callbacks correctly.